# Чистка каналов django channels

Tags: django

Здравствуйте, пишу чат на [django-channels](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Столкнулся с проблемой, что после перезагрузки сервера, старые каналы не удаляются из группы, но создаются новые. **Backend: 'asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer'**. Как "убить" все каналы при перезагрузке или же старый канал, для пользователя при коннекте?

Коннект консюмер:

```
def on_connect(message):
    Group('chat').add(message.reply_channel)
```

Дисконнект консюмер:

```
def on_disconnect(message):
    Group('chat').discard(message.reply_channel)
```

Answer (score 0):

А если add не делать, а попробовать отправлять в тот же канал?
Точнее пробовать отправлять, если не получится - то создавать канал.
Это только идея, channels сам только начал изучать.